# Etihad airlines didnt ask passport details when booking flight tickets, why?

Tags: air-travel, in-flight-services, etihad

I recently booked Etihad flight tickets from USA to INDIA and it didnt ask my passport details.

Comment: Many airlines don’t ask for this information at the point if booking. Is there a particular reason you are asking?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. You usually aren't required to provide passport information at booking, only at check-in. See e.g. *[Booking a flight without passport info](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116823)*